# How to iterate over an dictionary without knowing the keys, while getting key and object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, foundation

I have an NSDictionary and want to iterate over the objects. But at the same time, I need to know the key of the dictionary.

I remember there was a special, fancy form of fast enumeration, but have forgotten the exact syntax.

Anyone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
for (id key in dictionary) {
    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [dictionary objectForKey:key]);
}
```

Taken from [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: looks like the "normal form" of fast enumeration. same thing using an array returns an actual object. So this is actually really returning just the key, which then can be used to access the value? makes sense.

Answer (score 7):

This is also a good choice if you like blocks.

```
[dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {

}]
```

Comment: +1 This is probably *much* faster than the "fastEnumeration" variant (as it can make use of Core Foundation's `CFDictionaryApplyFunction`). It saves the expensive lookup for each element because it can simply iterate over the buckets and pass both key and value.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (id key in mydictionary) {
   id mything = [mydictionary objectForKey:key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[keyEnumerator](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/keyEnumerator)  returns an object that lets you iterate through each of the keys in the dictionary. From [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, at the time when you asked the question, there was only one way of traversing keys and values at the same time: [`CFDictionaryApplyFunction`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDictionaryRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFDictionaryApplyFunction).

Using this Core Foundation function involves an ugly C function pointer for the body of the loop and a lot of not-less-ugly, yet toll-free-bridged casting.

@zekel has the [modern way of iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12466764/104790) a dictionary. Vote him up!

Comment: By the way, `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:` was introduced in iOS 4, so four days after you asked this question :)